# What size UIToolbarbutton's icon should be?

Tags: ios7, xamarin.ios, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I'm trying to create a tool bar like below image. Surely I have different buttons and also different icons. But the question is that what size should be the icons that I will use for this buttons?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has extensive and very specific [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/BarIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH21-SW1) for icons and images in it's **iOS Human Interface Guidelines**.